# npm inssue babelify@10.0.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0

Tags: npm, dependencies

I am having problems with npm and babel/core/

I can't install the demo app from https://github.com/jakearchibald/wittr

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jakearchibald/wittr
$ npm install
```

I get

added 1053 packages from 526 contributors and audited 6107 packages in 29.719s
found 33 vulnerabilities (15 low, 17 high, 1 critical)
 run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

npm install --save-dev gulp@4.0.0 ws@6.0.0 browserify@16.2.3 babelify@10.0.0 gulp-babel@8.0.0 gulp-handlebars@5.0.2 handlebars@4.0.12 gulp-load-plugins@1.5.0 lodash@4.17.11

```
npm WARN babelify@10.0.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN gulp-babel@8.0.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ gulp-handlebars@5.0.2
+ babelify@10.0.0
+ gulp-babel@8.0.0
+ gulp@4.0.0
+ handlebars@4.0.12
+ gulp-load-plugins@1.5.0
+ ws@6.0.0
+ browserify@16.2.3
+ lodash@4.17.11
added 120 packages from 91 contributors, removed 143 packages, updated 54 packages and audited 10195 packages in 13.062s
found 4 vulnerabilities (3 low, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I got all the vulnerabilities down to just 1 high and 3 low. But npm run serve isn't working

I am running node 10.10.2 which is way above the recommended dependency of 0.12.7 so that should not be a problem

I'm using npm version 6.4.1

The package.json file is [here](https://github.com/jakearchibald/wittr/blob/master/package.json)

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing Babel 7, It should work

```
$ npm install --save-dev babelify @babel/core
```

I had the same issue, as you can see in the below image

[image]

After installing

[image]

Click on this for further information
[babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify)